# ¿Cómo sumar filas postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Quiero obtener la suma de los puntajes de cada candidata de acuerdo a los votos de cada juez.

Tengo la tabla puntaje;

```
id_puntaje  | p_traje1 | p_traje2 | p_pregunta | id_juez | id_candidata 
------------+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------
          6 |        9 |        8 |          0 |       0 |            3
          7 |        8 |      9.5 |          0 |       0 |            4
          8 |      9.7 |        9 |          0 |       0 |            5
          9 |        9 |      8.5 |          0 |       0 |            6
         10 |        7 |        8 |          0 |       0 |            7
         11 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       0 |            8
         12 |        8 |        8 |          0 |       0 |            9
         13 |      9.5 |      9.5 |          0 |       0 |           10
         14 |        8 |        7 |          0 |       1 |            3
         15 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       1 |            4
         16 |      9.8 |        9 |          0 |       1 |            5
         17 |        7 |      8.8 |          0 |       1 |            6
         18 |        8 |        9 |          0 |       1 |            7
         19 |        7 |        7 |          0 |       1 |            8
         20 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       1 |            9
         21 |      9.5 |        9 |          0 |       1 |           10
         22 |        7 |        8 |          0 |       2 |            3
         23 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       2 |            4
         24 |      9.7 |        6 |          0 |       2 |            5
         25 |        7 |        7 |          0 |       2 |            6
         26 |        8 |        8 |          0 |       2 |            7
         27 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       2 |            8
         28 |      9.7 |      9.7 |          0 |       2 |            9
         29 |      8.8 |        9 |          0 |       2 |           10
         30 |        8 |        8 |          0 |       3 |            3
         31 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       3 |            4
         32 |        7 |        7 |          0 |       3 |            5
         33 |      8.8 |      9.8 |          0 |       3 |            6
         34 |        8 |      9.8 |          0 |       3 |            7
         35 |        7 |        8 |          0 |       3 |            8
         36 |        8 |        9 |          0 |       3 |            9
         37 |        7 |        7 |          0 |       3 |           10
         38 |        9 |        7 |          0 |       4 |            3
         39 |        8 |        8 |          0 |       4 |            4
         40 |        7 |        9 |          0 |       4 |            5
         41 |      9.6 |        8 |          0 |       4 |            6
         42 |      9.1 |      9.2 |          0 |       4 |            7
         43 |        7 |        8 |          0 |       4 |            8
         44 |      8.8 |      8.9 |          0 |       4 |            9
         45 |      7.7 |        8 |          0 |       4 |           10
         46 |        9 |        9 |          0 |       5 |            3
         47 |      7.7 |        9 |          0 |       5 |            4
         48 |      8.1 |        8 |          0 |       5 |            5
         49 |      9.2 |      8.4 |          0 |       5 |            6
         50 |        7 |        8 |          0 |       5 |            7
         51 |        8 |        9 |          0 |       5 |            8
         52 |      8.8 |      8.5 |          0 |       5 |            9
         53 |        7 |      8.2 |          0 |       5 |           10
```

Para obtener la suma de las columnas de cada candidata tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p_traje1,0) + COALESCE(p_traje2,0) + COALESCE(p_pregunta,0) as p_total, id_candidata,id_juez
FROM puntaje
order by id_juez, id_candidata
```

Lo que me devuelve la suma total de los puntajes de cada juez para cada candidata

```
 p_total | id_candidata | id_juez 
---------+--------------+---------
      17 |            3 |       0
    17.5 |            4 |       0
    18.7 |            5 |       0
    17.5 |            6 |       0
      15 |            7 |       0
      18 |            8 |       0
      16 |            9 |       0
      19 |           10 |       0
      15 |            3 |       1
      18 |            4 |       1
    18.8 |            5 |       1
    15.8 |            6 |       1
      17 |            7 |       1
      14 |            8 |       1
      18 |            9 |       1
    18.5 |           10 |       1
      15 |            3 |       2
      18 |            4 |       2
    15.7 |            5 |       2
      14 |            6 |       2
      16 |            7 |       2
      18 |            8 |       2
    19.4 |            9 |       2
    17.8 |           10 |       2
      16 |            3 |       3
      18 |            4 |       3
      14 |            5 |       3
    18.6 |            6 |       3
    17.8 |            7 |       3
      15 |            8 |       3
      17 |            9 |       3
      14 |           10 |       3
      16 |            3 |       4
      16 |            4 |       4
      16 |            5 |       4
    17.6 |            6 |       4
    18.3 |            7 |       4
      15 |            8 |       4
    17.7 |            9 |       4
    15.7 |           10 |       4
      18 |            3 |       5
    16.7 |            4 |       5
    16.1 |            5 |       5
    17.6 |            6 |       5
      15 |            7 |       5
      17 |            8 |       5
    17.3 |            9 |       5
    15.2 |           10 |       5
```

Sin embargo lo que quiero obtener es la suma total de cada candidata, algo asi:

```
 p_total | id_candidata 
---------+--------------
      97 |            3 
     100 |            4 
     110 |            5 
      98 |            6 
      99 |            7
     100 |            8 
      99 |            9 
     103 |           10
```

Los valores de p_total son inventados ya que no he sacado la suma todavia.

**¿Qué consulta puedo hacer para obtener los que necesito?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto son las funciones de agregación. Tienes que usar `GROUP BY` y `SUM`:

```
SELECT  SUM(COALESCE(p_traje1,0) + 
            COALESCE(p_traje2,0) + 
            COALESCE(p_pregunta,0)) as p_total, 
        id_candidata
FROM puntaje
GROUP BY id_candidata
ORDER BY id_candidata
```

Comment: Gracias @Lamak, me sirvió tu respuesta.